# Old Tor users can affect my HS?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, vulnerability

Lets say a user is using a Tor version from 2013 and decides to connect to my HS that has the latest Tor client. Since the user has an old version of Tor, can the vulns in the Tor version reveal my IP? (Keep in mind that my HS is using the latest version of Tor but the client is using an old vulnerable version of Tor)

Answer (score 0):

No it won't affect you, because you've forgot about rendezvouz point : his path to RP *may be* affected, but not yours.